# MVC Form Submit ModelState Invalid-

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, modelstate

I am wanting to further my MVC learning. I do not understand why my form won't validate; well, actually I can read the message and it is straightforward enough but I can't find where I'm slipping up.

I'm only including what is relevant to the error message.

My model is this:

```
[Validator(typeof(ExtForumValidator))]
public partial class ExtrnlSubsModel : BaseEntityModel
{
   .....snip......
    public int ExtForumBoardId { get; set; }
}
```

My Validator:

```
public ExtForumValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService)
{
   RuleFor(x => x.ExtForumBoardId)
  .NotEqual(0).WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("ExternalForumBoards.Fields.AvailBoard.Required"));

}
```

Razor:

```
<td>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExtForumBoardId, Model.AvailableForumBoards)
   @Html.RequiredHint()
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AvailableForumBoards)
</td>
```

On submit all my other elements check out except this one has the ModelState error. For attempted value it shows as a string array???? 0,11 or 0,12 or 0,4 etc. It always has a zero and a comma prepended. The second number is correct as that is the id of the item selected in the drop down.

For exception it says null and for error message it says...well it says what I have for the validation message.

So it seems to me that it is getting hung up on this string array 0, stuff and I am at a loss as for where it comes from to go looking for the fix.

Comment: What is `AvailableForumBoards`? Can you View Source and see how the `select` control is being rendered?

Comment: AvailableForumBoards = new List<SelectListItem>();

Comment: <select name="ExternalSubscription.ExtForumBoardId" id="ExternalSubscription_ExtForumBoardId">
<option value="4">ForumA</option>
<option value="5">ForumB</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">Please Select</option>
</select>

Comment: That all looks fine, though I'm unfamiliar with your validator. What happens if you use `Data Annotations` instead?

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble....way down the page I had typod and had another field using ExtForumBoardId thus the double entry.